# Laravel Query Builder - Join three tables (A one to many B, B one to many C)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have three tables.

Country: id, country_name
State: id, country_id, state_name
City: id, state_id, city_name

I want to get a specific country ($id = 1) with all the cities in every state.
I try this code.

```
DB::table('country as a')
   ->join('state as b', 'b.country_id', '=', 'a.id')
   ->join('city as c', 'c.state_id', '=', 'b.id')
   ->select('a.*', 'b.*', 'c.*') 
   ->where('a.id', '=', $id)
   ->get();
```

And get results like this.

```
result: [
  {id: 1, country_id: 1, country_name: ABC, state_name: aaa, state_id: 0, city_name: city a1},
  {id: 2, country_id: 1, country_name: ABC, state_name: aaa, state_id: 0, city_name: city a2},
  {id: 3, country_id: 1, country_name: ABC, state_name: aaa, state_id: 0, city_name: city a3},
  {id: 4, country_id: 1, country_name: ABC, state_name: aaa, state_id: 0, city_name: city a4},
  {id: 5, country_id: 1, country_name: ABC, state_name: bbb, state_id: 1, city_name: city b1},
  {id: 6, country_id: 1, country_name: ABC, state_name: bbb, state_id: 1, city_name: city b2},
  {id: 7, country_id: 1, country_name: ABC, state_name: bbb, state_id: 1, city_name: city b3},
  {id: 8, country_id: 1, country_name: ABC, state_name: bbb, state_id: 1, city_name: city b4},
  .....
]
```

I hope can get results like this.

```
result: [
  {
    id: 1, 
    country_id: 1,
    country_name: ABC, 
    state_name: aaa, 
    state_id: 0, 
    city: [
      {city_name: city a1},
      {city_name: city a2},
      {city_name: city a3},
      {city_name: city a4}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    country_id: 1,
    country_name: ABC, 
    state_name: bbb, 
    state_id: 1, 
    city: [
      {city_name: city b1},
      {city_name: city b2},
      {city_name: city b3},
      {city_name: city b4}
    ]
  },
  .....
  and like that for other states.
]
```

Maybe someone can help me to give a new insight.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try adding groupBy('country_id') to your query

Comment: Do you have your models setup? if yes, then you can easily do this with relationships

Comment: No, I don't understand how to set up the models. Maybe you can give me advice. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leveraging Eloquent Relationships

**Models & Relationships**

```php
class Country extends Model
{
    public function states()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(State::class);
    }
}

class State extends Model
{
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }

    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
    }
}

class City extends Model
{
    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongTo(State::class);
    }
}
```

**Query**

```php
$countries = Country::query()
    ->with('states.cities')
    ->get();
```